How do I get this texture mapping for my quad (no triangles) to be perspective correct?
I'm working on a 3D Software Rasterizer and I'm wanting to render textures on walls now. I've tried to do it myself, but failed since it just distorts. I read up on the wikipedia page for Texture Mapping and found
\$(1-\alpha)u_0 + \alpha u_1\$
for affine mapping, and then:
$$\frac{(1-a) \frac{u_0}{z_0} + 
a\frac{u_1}{z_1}}
{(1-a)  \frac{1}{z_0} +  \alpha\frac{1}{z_1}}$$
for perspective correct mapping. However, as bright as I am, I managed to screw that up and it just distorts.
My Rasterizer is meant to be similar to the renderer DOOM has, by taking segments and projecting them as 3D, filling them going left from right as columns. My depth of the wall is based off of the projected Y coordinates for each point of the segment. I tried using these values for the z positions of the wall, and trying to use the reciprocals of them, but that doesn't work. I'm sure enough it's due to the mush brain I have that doesn't let me do this properly, as I'm certain that this would work for anything. My code has changed frequently, so I can't give anything else apart from what I have currently. I made something before, that was "close" to what I needed, but not exactly. I'd like some guidance on how I should do this properly. Thanks in advance, and apologies if I sound like an idiot at any point during this.


The textures will distort when I get up close, although, it can be seen on the left wall on the first picture. Here's the function for rasterizing the walls, sorry if it's messy.
@staticmethod
@njit(fastmath=True, parallel=True)
def rasterize(screenArray, x0, x1, y0, y1, y2, y3, col, wall_type, wall_visible, ceiling_lutT, ceiling_lutB, floor_lutT, floor_lutB, wall_portal, depth, depth_buffer, texture, wx0, wx1, wy0, wy1):
    ## cy is distance to camera
    backfacing = False
    if x0 > x1:
        x1, x0 = x0, x1
        y1, y0, y3, y2 = y0, y1, y2, y3
        backfacing = True
    dyb = y1-y0
    dyt = y3-y2
    dx = max(x1-x0, 1)

    X0 = max(min(int(x0), W1), 1)
    X1 = max(min(int(x1), W1), 1)
    for x in prange(X0, X1):
        Y1=dyb*(x-x0)/dx+y0
        Y2=dyt*(x-x0)/dx+y2
        for y in prange(int(Y2), int(Y1)):
            if not (x > W1 or x < 1 or y > H1 or y < 1):
                PY0 = 0
                PY1 = 0
                if wall_portal:
                    PY1=Y1
                    PY0=Y2
                else:
                    PY1=Y2
                    PY0=Y1
                if backfacing:
                    if wall_type == 0:
                        ceiling_lutB[x] = PY1
                        floor_lutB[x] = PY0
                    elif wall_type == 1:
                        floor_lutB[x] = PY0
                    elif wall_type == 2:
                        ceiling_lutB[x] = PY1
                else:
                    if wall_type == 0:
                        ceiling_lutT[x] = PY1
                        floor_lutT[x] = PY0
                    elif wall_type == 1:
                        floor_lutT[x] = PY0
                    elif wall_type == 2:
                        ceiling_lutT[x] = PY1
                if wall_visible:
                    if depth_buffer[x, y] > depth:
                        depth_buffer[x, y] = depth
                    else:
                        continue
                    
                    z0 = wy0
                    z1 = wy1
                    a = (x - x0) / (x1 - x0)

                    u = ((1 - a) * 0 + a * 1)
                    a = (y-Y2)/(Y1-Y2)
                    v = (1 - a) * 0 + a * 1
                    
                    texture_col = texture[int(u*64)%64, int(v*64)%64]
                    screenArray[x, y] = texture_col
                    
    return ceiling_lutT, ceiling_lutB, floor_lutT, floor_lutB


I converted your math text to formatted MathJax. Based on your links, I took a to be  α and x to be multiplication - if I got that wrong, please edit as needed to make corrections.

No, you're all good. That fancy 'x' symbol you see in maths exists, so no worries :)
